# How can I calculate the perimeter of an object in an image?

Tags: python, image-segmentation

I have an image. I want to get the perimeter of every object in my image. For example, [in this image](https://image.ibb.co/i2yzqn/perimeter.png) , the perimeter of an object is 33 (the number of pixels at its edges).
I have written the following algorithm, but it is very timely.

Does anyone have an idea to increase the speed of the algorithm?

What I have tried:

```
def cal_perimeter_object(object, image):
peri_ = 0
for pixel_ in image:
    if pixel_is_in_neigbor_of_object() is True:
        peri_ += 1

return peri_
```

Comment: Is your object a boolean mask for the image? How does your algorithm know, what is object and what background?

Comment: I find all of objects in image and then want to calculate the perimeter of all objects.

Comment: That is understood. But HOW do you mark them? What should the algorithm use to identify objects and calculate the perimeter of each object? Do you use [scipy.ndimage.label](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html)? Or the below mentioned scikit-image? Depending on this, the strategy will differ.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by @Piinthesky having a boolean (or labelled image) where you know the label for the object you want to find the contour for is the first step. There are a number of ways of doing this, the simplest of which is thresholding. Once you have your labelled image you can find the perimeter in a number of ways - e.g. the number of pixels along the border. To give you a head start here is a way to do it on the image you put in the [link](https://image.ibb.co/i2yzqn/perimeter.png). I have used [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) but there are other python libraries you may use.

```
# If your python version is not 3.x uncomment line below
#from __future__ import print_function
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
import skimage.io as io
# read in the image (enter the path where you downloaded it on your computer below
im = io.imread('/home/kola/Downloads/perimeter.png')
# To simplify things I am only using the first channel and thresholding
# to get a boolean image
bw = im[:,:,0] > 230
regions = regionprops(bw.astype(int))
print(regions[0].perimeter)
```